# Lower and Upper Bounds of $n(A∪B)$, without knowing $n(A∩B)$.

Tags: combinatorics

Let's assume that I have a set $A$, with $n(A)$ number of elements, and set $B$, with $n(B)$ numbers of elements inside. How can I use this information to find out the lower and upper bounds of the union and intersection of both sets? I found the formula 
$$n(A∪B)=n(A)+n(B)-n(A∩B)$$ 
however this equation requires one to have the value of $n(A∩B)$, which I don't have. Therefore my question is, is there a way to calculate the lower and upper bounds of $n(A∩B)$ so that I can do the same for $n(A∪B)$?

Comment: There has to be a minus, the correct formula should be
$n(A\cup B)=n(A)+n(B)-n(A\cap B)$.

Comment: the formula should be $n(A\cup B)=n(A)+n(B)-n(A\cap B)$ (Btw, this tells you immediately that $n(A)+n(B)$ is an upper bound of $n(A\cup B)$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $A$ and $B$ are disjoint the union is as large as possible so
$$
n(A∪B)=n(A)+n(B) 
$$
is an upper bound. (In this case $n(A∩B) = 0$.)

When one is a subset of the other the union is as small as possible, so
$$
n(A∪B)=\max(n(A), n(B))
$$
is a lower bound.
(In this case $n(A∩B) = \min(n(A), n(B))$.)

Comment: How did you work out the lower bound of $n(A∩B)$?

Comment: When one of the sets is a subset of the other the union is the larger one. The subtraction in the general formula cancels the contribution of the smaller one. Draw some pictures of dots surrounded by circles in various configurations and you will see what's going on.

Comment: The lower bound is the _maximum_, not the _minimum_. Please draw yourself some pictures with about $6$ points and experiment with various choices for $A$ and $B$.

Comment: a general answer for the intersection size is described in the article "Extremal intersection sizes" available online here (p.535):
   http://www.pme-math.org/journal/issues/PMEJ.Vol.11.No10.pdf